# How to replace $arg.name powershell, instead of doing $argname = get-item $arg | select -ExpandProperty Name

Tags: file, powershell, move

```
$argname = get-item $arg | select -ExpandProperty Name
```

it does pass only the name to the variable $argname from $arg which comes from the default $args passed to powershell from command line or from a shortcut which is the case.
I read around Microsoft site and here a lot of code and saw some examples using .name after the variable, but every attempt i made to replace:

```
robocopy $arg $DestinationDir\$argname /e /xf *.*
robocopy $arg $DestinationDir\$argname /mov /xf *.tmp /e
```

For:

```
robocopy $arg $DestinationDir\$arg.name /e /xf *.*
robocopy $arg $DestinationDir\$arg.name /mov /xf *.tmp /e
$($arg.name) returns a null value
```

Results in a total failure.

Does anyone know how to extract the last directory name from a variable, for instance, data from $arg = "c:\something", i wanted it to use in such a way that i could use the extraction in the same line without being forced to create another or change the original variable.

The idea of the script is to move all the files leaving dummy files behind.
My complete script is:

```
$Extension = @("*.flac","*.m4a","*.mp4","*.mp3")
$destinationDir = "E:\renab"
ForEach($arg in $args){
$files = get-ChildItem -path $arg -recurse -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" -include $Extension
$argname = get-item $arg | select -ExpandProperty Name
robocopy $arg $DestinationDir\$argname /e /xf *.*
robocopy $arg $DestinationDir\$argname /mov /xf *.tmp /e
ForEach($file in $files){
    New-Item -Path "$($file.Directory)\$($file.Name)" -ItemType "file" -Value ""
    }   
}
```

Comment: Might be as simple as `robocopy $arg $DestinationDir\$($arg.name) /e /xf *.*`

Comment: I had tried that already, but for some weird reason the results are:

From 

echo $DestinationDir\$($arg.name)

E:\renab\

$argname = get-item $arg | select -ExpandProperty Name

echo $DestinationDir\$argname

E:\renab\XXXX

meaning that the attribute .name from the var is null if used from the received $args

i'm not sure if this is a bug or just i'm not seeing something there.